# Can I enter France with an Italian Schengen Visa under coronavirus situation?

Tags: schengen, france, italy, greece, covid-19

I understand that there will be some issues.

I have got a single entery Italian Schengen Visa valid early April for 2 weeks. But because of the coronavirus, Italy is under lockdown, which means that I am unable to make my trip as planned.

Now if I changed my planned destination and to visit Greece (by flight via Paris) instead, can I enter France with my already issued Italian Schengen Visa?

I can provide my new air ticket and hotel reservations, but I won't go to Italy at all. What other options I can choose if I need to make the trip on the same dates?

Comment: You are almost certainly going to need a new Schengen visa from Greece or France.

Comment: The best strategy is to request an revocation of your Italian-issued Schengen visa in favour of one issued by Greece.

Comment: E-mail the French border police at dcpaf-em-cnic@interieur.gouv.fr and explain the situation. Only they will be authorised to advise on how it will be handled at the border

Answer (score 8):

EDIT: This is a fast evolving situation. Under the current circumstances I suggest anyone planning to come to Europe just cancel or postpone.

A Schengen visa normally allows one to enter any Schengen country. 
There is no obligation to enter the Schengen area through the country that issued your visa. 
So entering via France (or any other country) is not an issue. 
It is pretty common even.

The rule that you must apply to the consulate of the country that is your main destination exists to spread the workload, and to counter visa shopping. 
To enforce that rule the immigration officer stamping you in may want to see hotel and flight reservations proving that indeed you plan to follow the itinerary on your Schengen Visa application. 
Arriving at the border with evidence suggesting that your plans are very different from those stated in your application will raise red flags, and may lead to a refusal.

This under normal circumstances. 
However we are no longer under normal circumstances. 
Deciding to no longer visit Italy is completely reasonable in light of the current situation. 
So I would guess that cutting Italy out of your plans is not going to raise a red flag. 
You should however inquire with the French consulate and the  French border police (dcpaf-em-cnic@interieur.gouv.fr).

One last thing: 
The way things are currently progressing all of Europe will be where Italy is now in about 10 days (and so might your home country). 
You might want to completely postpone your trip.

Comment: Add to that that Italy will probably not let you in anyway,  if you did arrive there. This is a very realistic answer and the given advice should be taken.

Comment: "You should however contact the French consulate and inquire." Disagree, as they will have no say at the border. OP should e-mail the French border police (dcpaf-em-cnic@interieur.gouv.fr)